# perl regex matching failed

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match two different string and output should come in $1 and $2, 
According to me in this example, if $a is 'xy abc', then $1 should be 'xy abc' and $2 should 'abc', but 'abc' part is coming in $3. 
Can you please help me to writing a regex in that $1 should have whole string and $2 should 
have second part.
I am using perl 5.8.5.

```
my @data=('abc xy','xy abc');
foreach my $a ( @data) {
    print "\nPattern= $a\n";
    if($a=~/(abc (xy)|xy (abc))/) {
        print "\nMatch: \$1>$1< \$2>$2< \$3>$3<\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
perl test_reg.pl

Pattern= abc xy

Match: $1>abc xy< $2>xy< $3><

Pattern= xy abc

Match: $1>xy abc< $2>< $3>abc<
```

Comment: "I am using perl 5.8.5." That's eight years old. You should really consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only one of captures `$2` and `$3` can be defined, you can write

```
foreach my $item ( @data) {

  print "\nPattern= $item\n";

  if ($item=~/(abc (xy)|xy (abc))/) {
    printf "Match: whole>%s< part>%s<\n", $1, $2 || $3;
  }
}
```

which gives the output

```
Pattern= abc xy
Match: whole>abc xy< part>xy<

Pattern= xy abc
Match: whole>xy abc< part>abc<
```

Answer (score 4):

Can be done with:

```
(?|(abc (xy))|(xy (abc)))
```

Why even bother with capturing the whole thing? You can use `$&` for that.

```
my @data = ('abc xy', 'xy abc');
for(@data) {
    print "String: '$_'\n";

    if(/(?|abc (xy)|xy (abc))/) {
        print "Match: \$&='$&', \$1='$1'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cylian, quoted from `perlre`: *"This is the "branch reset" pattern, which has the special property that the capture groups are numbered from the same starting point in each alternation branch."*

Comment: +1, At first it seems an error! But nothing but my ignorance!

Comment: I am getting this error and one more thing
I want $1 should contain 'abc xy' or 'xy abc' and $2 should contain 
'xy' and 'abc'.
Sequence (?|...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?| <-- HERE (abc (xy))|(xy (abc)))/ at test_reg.pl line 5.

Comment: @user87005, you need Perl 5.10 for `(?|...)`. I'd suggest upgrading perl to something from this decade if possible. ;-)

Comment: I cannot use 5.10. Any other solution in 5.8.

Comment: @user87005, not really. The only thing you can do is to use things like `/(foo (bar)|bar (foo)) (xxx)/; print "val: '$2$3', next: '$4'";`.

Comment: @user87005, keeping track of the groups your self is the only way to do it in 5.8, if that is not good enough for you then the answer to your question is: *It can't be done in 5.8*.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with allowing more capture variables than `$1` and `$2`, then use the substrings from the branch of the alternative that matched.

```
for ('abc xy', 'xy abc') {
  print "[$_]:\n";

  if (/(abc (xy))|(xy (abc))/) {
    print "  - match: ", defined $1 ? "1: [$1], 2: [$2]\n"
                                    : "1: [$3], 2: [$4]\n";
  }
  else {
    print "  - no match\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[abc xy]:
  - match: 1: [abc xy], 2: [xy]
[xy abc]:
  - match: 1: [xy abc], 2: [abc]
```